# Don't understand why this TypeError occurs when attempting to call inherited method

Tags: python, inheritance, linked-list, python-3.6, python-import

First, I am using python 3.6.

I am trying `import` and use my own .py file in my project. I `import` my `LinkedList.py` file and create a `Mylist` class, which extends the imported file's class.

When I try the construct an instance of the `Mylist` class, which involves creating an instance of my `inheritedLinkedList` derived class, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*/PycharmProjects/Veri Yapilari/lists.py", line 65, in <module>
    test = Mylist()
  File "*/PycharmProjects/Veri Yapilari/lists.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.linkedlist = inheritedLinkedList()
  File "*/PycharmProjects/Veri Yapilari/lists.py", line 8, in __init__
    super.__init__()
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'super' object needs an argument
```

Here's the section of the code where the problem occurs:

```
test = Mylist()
test.insertFirstM(incomingDataM=4)  # <- Causes a TypeError.
```

Below is the main script in its entirety:

```
import LinkedList as myLinkedList


class inheritedLinkedList(myLinkedList.DoublyLinkedList):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()
    def raplaceElements(self, dataToBeChanged, incomingData):
        position = self.find(dataToBeChanged)
        position.data = incomingData
    def swapElements(self, swap1, swap2):
        position1 = self.find(swap1)
        prev1 = position1.previous
        next1 = position1.next
        position2 = self.find(swap2)
        prev2 = position2.previous
        next2 = position2.next

        prev1.next = position1
        position1.previous = prev1
        position1.next = next1
        next1.previous = position1

        prev2.next = position2
        position2.previous = prev2
        position2.next = next2
        next2.previous = position2
    def insertBefore(self, incomingData, previousNode=None):
        self.insert(incomingData, self.find(previousNode).previous.data)


class Mylist:
    def __init__(self):
#        self.linkedlist = inheritedLinkedList;
        self.linkedlist = inheritedLinkedList()  # Per martineau's suggestion.

    def replaceElements(self, dataToBeChanged, incomingData):
        self.linkedlist.raplaceElements(dataToBeChanged, incomingData)

    def swapElements(self, swap1, swap2):
        self.linkedlist.swapElements(swap1, swap2)

    def insertFirstM(self, incomingDataM):
        self.linkedlist.insertFirst(incomingDataM)

    def insertLast(self, incomingData):
        self.linkedlist.insert(incomingData)

    def insertAfter(self, incomingData, incomingNode):
        self.linkedlist.insert(incomingData, incomingNode)

    def insertBefore(self, incomingData, incomingNode):
        self.linkedlist.insert(incomingData, incomingNode)

    def remove(self, incomingData):
        self.linkedlist.remove(incomingData)

    def listprint(self):
        self.linkedlist.listprint()


test = Mylist()
test.insertFirstM(4)
```

The code for the imported `LinkedList` module (`LinkedList.py`) can be obtained—if needed—by downloading it from my [github repository](https://github.com/EmreKARAgh/unCompleteList).

Comment: `list` is a python builtin. Your initialization is wrong as well. You need to use `super().__init__()` assuming you are using python >= 3.6.

Comment: It would best if you just showed the code you're running along with a copy of the error traceback (in your question, not as an image) you're getting.

Comment: Thank You. I rename my class like "list" to "MyList" and use super.__init__() in "inheritedlinkedlist"'s __init__() method. but it didnt done yet.

Comment: Note that "ı" is not the English pronoun "I".

Comment: Thanks @martineau I think we done :)

Comment: The `self.linkedlist = inheritedLinkedList` assignment sets the value of the `linkedlist` attribute to the ***class*** `inheritedLinkedList`, not an instance of it. This means the `self.linkedlist.insertFirst(incomingDataM)` is trying to call `inheritedLinkedList.insertFirst()` which is an **unbound** class instance method (so is missing the required initial `self` instance argument). I think maybe you need `self.linkedlist = inheritedLinkedList()`.

Comment: @martineau I try both of "super.__init()__"  and  "self.linkedlist = inheritedLinkedList()" but they didnt work

Comment: EmreKara: You likely getting a different error—what is it? Can you put enough code in your question to allow it be run? If you do that, then others will be able to reproduce the problem and maybe help you better.

Comment: @martineau Thaks for your advice. I added it to my question

Comment: EmreKara: No you didn't follow my advice: 1. What's the new error after the change? 2. Posting a link to you code isn't the same as putting runnable code here so others can work on the problem and later others can see how the problem was fixed. I believe that making the suggested change has simply allowed another bug in your code to become apparent because more of it is starting to execute for the first time.

Comment: Sorry @martineau you right.  I don't know how to add runnable Python code here but I update my code and my error.

Comment: The `TypeError` you're currently getting is because of not using [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) properly—it's a function that needs to be called. Try changing the code in the `inheritedLinkedList.__init__():` method to `super().__init__()` (assuming you're using Python 3) similar to what is shown in the documentation. Also note that the title of your question no longer matches the problem.

Comment: Although it's not strictly necessary, I also suggest you rename your derived class `InheritedLinkedList` so its name conforms to the [naming-conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions/) suggested in the PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, you're not using the [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) built-in correctly. Try do things this way instead (so it's like the example in the linked documentation):

```
class inheritedLinkedList(myLinkedList.DoublyLinkedList):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Change line to this.
```

Actually, since the derived class' `__init__()` is currently doing nothing but that, it's not even necessary because that's what would occur automatically if the subclass didn't define its own. In other words, the following would accomplish the same thing:

```
class inheritedLinkedList(myLinkedList.DoublyLinkedList):
#    ** NOT REALLY NEEDED AT ALL **
#    def __init__(self):
#        super().__init__()
```

P.S. You also ought to change the very end of the **`LinkedList.py`** script so the last few lines that are there don't execute when it's `import`ed as a module by `lists.py`:

```
            ...
            nextNode.previous = previousNode
            dataToBeDeleted.next = dataToBeDeleted.previous = None

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Should add this, too.

    list1 = SinglyLinkedList()
    list2 = DoublyLinkedList()

    list2.insertFirst(6)
```